# Android - Facebook GraphUser has no email attribute

Tags: android, facebook, email

I've checked and double-checked online sources regarding the issue - but I still can't get the  email attribute from the Facebook Response.

As indicated on the Getting Started, I implemented the read permissions ("basic_auth", "email", "user_birthday") on the LoginButton. Also set the same permissions when creating a session (Session.createFromExistingAccessToken). However, on the callback function, when Logging the GraphUser and Response object, I still wasn't able to retrieve the email of the user.

What are the possible reasons on why the error is still persisting? Am I missing some steps?

```
**onCreate()**

    ((LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.dialog_generic_footer_button_fblogin))
                .setPublishPermissions(FBSessionV2.getPermissions());
```

**Facebook session class**

```
...
    public static ArrayList<String> getPermissions(){
       if (PERMISSIONS.isEmpty()){
        PERMISSIONS.add("basic_info");
        PERMISSIONS.add("email");
        PERMISSIONS.add("publish_actions");
        PERMISSIONS.add("user_birthday");
       }
       return PERMISSIONS;
    }
...
```

**WebDialog.onCompleteListener**

```
session = Session.getActiveSession();

if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()){
    Logger.log(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(), "calling accesstoken" + values, Log.DEBUG);
    AccessToken at = AccessToken.createFromExistingAccessToken(values.getString("access_token"), null, null, AccessTokenSource.WEB_VIEW, FBSessionV2.getPermissions());
    session = Session.openActiveSessionWithAccessToken(ControllerBase.getInstance().getActivity(), at, cb);
} else {
    Logger.log(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(), "calling openactivesession", Log.DEBUG);
    Session.openActiveSession(ControllerBase.getInstance().getActivity(), true, cb);
}
```

**GraphUserCallback()**

```
...
    userProfile.put("facebookId", user.getId());
    userProfile.put("email", user.getProperty("email"));
    userProfile.put("first_name", user.getFirstName());
    userProfile.put("last_name", user.getLastName());
    userProfile.put("name", user.getName());
    userProfile.put("gender", user.getProperty("gender"));
    userProfile.put("birthday", user.getBirthday());
    if (user.getProperty("email") != null){
        userProfile.put("email", (String) user.getProperty("email"));
    }
...
```

**UPDATE**

It seems we're only having trouble when we're trying to log-in a Facebook account that is not a Developer (and may as well be Administrator) of the Facebook app. We just tried to log-in one of our FB account that has a Developer role - and it succeeds.

However, since the app will be made for public use, this still doesn't solve our problem (may as well be treated as a band-aid fix for now - I still need to further investigate the issue).

Comment: Try below solution and let me know whether it is working or not...

Answer (score 2):

Try using this way,

```
String email = user.asMap().get("email").toString();
```

and then you can pass this string parameter to print email like

```
TextView mEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
mEmail.setText(email);
```

By this way i am successfully able to get email-id.

Comment: Hello there! I've tried that and sadly its still not working, the user object itself doesn't have any email attribute when I logged it - thus, getting a null value on the .get("email").

Comment: But i am using same above code and i am getting user's email as well. Can you post your whole code.

Comment: As requested here's the whole singleton class for my implementation. http://pastie.org/private/75jh534uics5zvxdfs9tzw.

Are there other factors as to why I can't get the email attribute? For example, previous session clearing, facebook account age, facebook app configuration, etc?

Comment: Upvoted the answer as it really is one way to retrieve the email attribute. However due to some strange occurrence, public FB accounts will still not be able to get the email attribute. **apparently I can't upvote yet :)**

Comment: Is your app in sandbox mode?

Answer (score 2):

Probably your app is in sandbox mode. Please have a look here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/#sandbox

It's saying

> Please note that when your app is in Sandbox Mode, you cannot call any
>   API calls on behalf of users who cannot see your app.

Comment: Hello there! I've just checked on the application page, and no - the application is not on sandbox mode. In the Status and Review page, the  "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" is set to Yes